# redirect uri mismatch passport js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to do a google login using passport js and express but I'm getting redirect uri mismatch error over and over again. I checked multiple times that redirect uri in my code is the same as in the google developer console but the issue still persists.

passport js config:

```
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import db from "../../lib/database.js";

export default function (passport: passport.PassportStatic) {
  passport.use(
    new Strategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback",
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const user = db.user.findFirst({
          where: {
            authProvider: "google",
            authProviderId: profile.id,
          },
        });
        if (!user) {
          const newUser = db.user.create({
            data: {
              authProvider: "google",
              authProviderId: profile.id,
              name: profile.displayName,
              email: profile.emails[0].value,
            },
          });
          return done(null, newUser);
        }
        return done(null, user);
      }
    )
  );
}
```

auth router:

```
import passport from "passport";
import express from "express";
import passportConfig from "../configs/passportConfig.js";
passportConfig(passport);

const router = express.Router();

router.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })
);

router.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  function (req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect("/");
  }
);

export default router;
```

authorized redirect uris in google console:
[image: authorized redirect uris in google console]

[image: error screen]

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:3000` ?

Comment: yes, I've tried ```http://localhost:3000``` but it's the same error

Comment: I have tried `http://localhost:8000` and `http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback` with your code and it works. Is your `clientID` and `clientSecret` correct ?

Comment: thank you for trying and helping out. I've actually ditched passport and decided to send my requests directly to google apis without third-party libraries and got everything working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little bit late but actually, I ditched passport altogether and decided to implement google login without third-party libraries. I tested my implementation and everything seems to be working fine. Here's the code:

socialClient:

```
export type tokens = {
  access_token: string;
  id_token?: string;
};

export type socialUser = {
  authProviderId: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  authProvider: string;
};

export interface ISocialClient {
  getUser(tokens: tokens): Promise<socialUser>;
}

abstract class SocialClient {
  client_id: string;
  client_secret: string;
  redirect_uri: string;
  scope: string;
  constructor(client_id: string, client_secret: string, redirect_uri: string, scope: string) {
    this.client_id = client_id;
    this.client_secret = client_secret;
    this.redirect_uri = redirect_uri;
    this.scope = scope;
  }
  abstract generateAuthUrl(): string;
  abstract getTokens(code: string): Promise<tokens>;
  abstract getUser(tokens: tokens): Promise<socialUser>;
}

export default SocialClient;
```

googleClient:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import querystring from "query-string";
import axios from "axios";
import SocialClient from "../socialClient.js";
import { type tokens, ISocialClient, type socialUser } from "../socialClient.js";

class GoogleClient extends SocialClient implements ISocialClient {
  grant_type: string;
  static instance: GoogleClient;
  private constructor(
    client_id: string,
    client_secret: string,
    redirect_uri: string,
    grant_type: string,
    scope: string
  ) {
    super(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, scope);
    this.grant_type = grant_type;
  }
  static getInstance() {
    if (!GoogleClient.instance) {
      GoogleClient.instance = new GoogleClient(
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL as string,
        "authorization_code",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
      );
    }
    return GoogleClient.instance;
  }
  generateAuthUrl() {
    const rootUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
    const options = {
      redirect_uri: process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL,
      client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      access_type: "offline",
      response_type: "code",
      prompt: "consent",
      scope: [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
      ].join(" ")
    };
    return `${rootUrl}?${querystring.stringify(options)}`;
  }
  async getTokens(code: string): Promise<tokens> {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
        code: code,
        client_id: this.client_id,
        client_secret: this.client_secret,
        redirect_uri: this.redirect_uri,
        grant_type: this.grant_type,
        scope: this.scope
      });
      const access_token: string = response.data.access_token;
      const id_token: string = response.data.id_token;
      return { access_token, id_token };
    } catch (e: any) {
      throw new Error("The code passed is incorrect or expired");
    }
  }
  async getUser(tokens: tokens): Promise<socialUser> {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=${tokens.access_token}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens.id_token}`
          }
        }
      );
      return {
        authProviderId: response.data.id,
        email: response.data.email,
        name: response.data.name,
        authProvider: "google"
      };
    } catch {
      throw new Error("could not get user data");
    }
  }
}

export default GoogleClient;
```